# AsyncPostBackTrigger of button not firing the custom alert

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

Hi all I am having a button on my form for which I have used an updatepanel with `AsyncPostBackTrigger` every thing works fine but what ever code I have written to show a custom alert is getting executed but the alert is not firing can some one help me

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server">
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="button1" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

 protected void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if(somecondition)
    {
      // code
    }
    else
    {
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(.....);
    }
 }
```

Comment: That's not going to work because of the way UpdatePanel's PartialPostBacks work.  If you want to do an alert, run it all in JavaScript, or switch to ModalPopup.

Answer (score 1):

When using Update panel, you should use [ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(updatePanelId,updatePanelId.GetType()
                                   , "key_name", "alert('Hello');", true)
```

Check [this link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=200) for complete explanation/details.